# How to delete everything after first space in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a column in a data frame with dates in the format of “1/4/2021 0:00”. And I would like to get rid of everything after the first space, including the first space so that way it becomes “1/4/2021”.

How can I do that in Python? Also, does the column already have to be a specific data type in order to complete this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas you can try the following, assuming the entire column is following a similar datetime format.

Your dataframe is called `df`, and your column of dates is `date`.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

or 

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.date)

or

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.normalize()
```

Depending on what you want the format of your date column to be.

Comment: Thanks. Does this column already have to be date data type or could it be a string?

Comment: can you show me some rows of the dates from your dataframe and the output of df.dtypes or df['date'].dtype ? it should work with the format in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Note that this code only works if your column in data frame has type `string`.
In order to check the data type, run: `df.dtypes`.